# What happens to the app when I press the icon from home screen but it is already running?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Imagine you're using an app, then you press the home button. The app is already running, but it isn't visible to you. You then press the app icon again to bring the app back to the front.

What gets called in the code? What gets called in the ViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    //In appDelegate class following delegate method called when you hit home button
     func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication)
        {

        }
        // this EnterBackground delegate is called
        func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication)
        {

        }

     //When you tap on app icon again following 2 delegate methods called
   func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication)
    {

    }
        //finally when your app become active
        func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication)
        {

        }

    //This called when app terminates
       func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication)
        {

        }

    This is called life cycle of app.
```

Comment: I'd add to directly answer your question, nothing automatically gets called in the ViewController.

Comment: Thanks!! Nothing automatically called in viewController but you can call viewController method by creating protocol and delegate in viewController. Means if you want to update something on viewController like refresh. You can do using delegate.

Comment: Interesting. I seem to have a bug where a UITableView changes positions when I press the home button then go back into it. I don't see anything here that would redraw when I bring it back up.

Edit: Maybe it is just in the simulator..

Comment: When you press home button is it changing tableView position automatically or you are changing? When you relaunch the app nothing you see. Are you using AutoLayout. I would recommend in this method applicationDidBecomeActive get the rootViewController view and enumerate the all objects in view their coordinate point they should be there I guess their coordinate point got shifted

Comment: I don't do anything. I just press home. Then I press the app icon to get back in, and it shifts. I'm not changing anything. I do use auto-layout.

Comment: may be your orientation is getting changed portrait to landscape. I guess its issue of Auto-Layout constrains. May be subviews constrains are not persisting its loosing when you hit the home button. I never had this kind of  issue with auto-layout.

Comment: Honestly, I'm doing things a bit unorthodox in that I am making Twitter-like paging navigation, and one of my View Controllers which is a page gets lowered and pushed a bit to the right whenever I press home button, then press app icon to get back into the app... I also only let my app be used in portrait mode

Answer (score 1):

You've got a file called `AppDelegate.swift`. In there you find per default 5 methods.

As you can see, there's already a nice description when the function get called:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]!) -> Bool {
    //Called if the app is started
          return true
}


func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {

    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I seem to have a bug where a UITableView changes positions when I press the home button then go back into it. I don't see anything here that would redraw when I bring it back up.